# std::forward not passing lvalue reference

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue, perfect-forwarding

I am probably missing something basic here, but why don't I get a lvalue from `std:forward` bellow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void f(const T& lhs) {
  std::cout << "lvalue" << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
void f(const T&& rhs) { // const, so as not to have a universal reference 
  std::cout << "rvalue" << "\n";
}

int main() {
  auto a = 3;
  f(a); // lvalue
  f(3); // rvalue
  f(std::forward<int>(a)); // rvalue ???
}
```

this compiles to

```
lvalue
rvalue
rvalue
```

I would expect the last result to be a lvalue.

Comment: I'd try with a *type* that can be actually moved

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, thank you. I usually use it with template parameter packs and my mind failed me here. I guess my brain got used to seeing those `Ts` and `Args` ...

Comment: @MatG I get the same behaviour even with a custom class (that has a proper move constructor).

Answer (score 3):

`std::forward` is a conditional `std::move`. Using it only makes sense inside of a template, where you choose whether to move or not depending on a template argument.

Like this:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T &&value)
{
    f(std::forward<T>(value));
}
```

Here, `T &&value` is called a *forwarding reference* (as long `T` is deduced by the compiler, rather than specified manually), i.e. can accept both lvalues and rvalues.

If you pass an rvalue to this function, `T` is deduced to a non-reference, so `T &&value` remains an rvalue reference.

If you pass an lvalue, `T` is deduced to an lvalue reference, and `T &&value` becomes an lvalue reference (see [reference collapsing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)).

To work with forwarding references, `std::forward` acts as an `std::move` if its template argument is not a reference, and does nothing if its template argument is an lvalue reference.

Since you passed a non-reference to it, you got a move, but again, it's not its intended use case.

Comment: But I don't have a forwarding reference here, that's why I'm using `const T&&` so that I can overload with different functionality for lvalues and rvalues - else, `T&&` would be also called for lvalues (and even in the presence of `const T&`). With a `const T&&` it no longer makes sense to have `std::forward` in the template as it will not be called for lvalues anyhow, does it?

Comment: @MarinosK *"I don't have a forwarding reference"* Exactly my point, you're misusing `std::forward`, so it gives you weird results. (Note that I'm **not** talking about `f` not having a forwarding reference param, but rather about `forward` not being inside of a function that has a forwarding reference param.) The penultimate paragraph explains how `forward` decides whether to move or not, and the move condition only makes sense if the template parameter you give it comes from a forwarding reference.

Comment: Your "you passed a non-reference to it" made me realise that this is the problem.. My code is OK simply with `std::forward<int&>(a)`.

Comment: no! `std:move(a)` returns a rvalue while `std:forward(a)` returns a lvalue.

Comment: @MarinosK Yep, sorry, my bad. `std::forward<int>(a)` is equivalent to `std::move(a)`, but `std::forward<int&>(a)` does nothing and is equivalent to just `a`.

Comment: I've summed this in an answer of mine above - many thanks, this has been enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

@HolyBlackCat's answer made me realise the problem and the solution. I'm not returning a reference from `std:forward` but an `int` so that's indeed a rvalue (since it doesn't have an address). With `std::forward<int&>` it's indeed correctly forwarding the lvalue reference. So this:

```
  f(a); // lvalue
  f(3); // rvalue
  f(std::move(a)); // rvalue
  f(std::forward<int>(a)); // rvalue !!!
  f(std::forward<int&>(a)); // lvalue
```

correctly returns

```
lvalue
rvalue
rvalue
rvalue
lvalue
```